# Unknown character / word

Tags: java, android

```
Sentences : 
Test Your Skills 1, ... 2, ... 3, ....
Specify Your Skills 1, ..2, ...3, ....
Check Your Skills 1, ..2, ...3, ....
```

..

```
restofsentence="Your Skills"+ ? ;
String test = "Test" + restofsentence
String specify = "Specify" + restofsentence
String check = "Check" + restofsentence
```

How can I define restofsentence variable, "?" must define any number

'test = "Test Your Skills 6" ', 'test = "Test Your Skills 36" '  all must be pair without using loop because we dont know last number

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.format()` method for that.

```
String format = "%1$s your skill %2$d";
String test = String.format(format, "Test", 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to use ´String format´ alone ? I mean ´format = Specify Your Skills 12´  also  ´format = Test Your Skills 7´

Comment: You can assemble any kind of string by just appending them like `test = "Test" +" your skill " + 7;`